# How to Crop a UiImage to specific Size?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, crop, scaling

Hi I am working with the UIimage, I need to crop my image to specific size, Suppose my specific  size width is equal to device width and height is fixed 200.
I tried in Google lot of examples but non of those not working for me, I tried below samples

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    float h=200;
    float w=400;


    float actualHeight = image.size.height;
    float actualWidth = image.size.width;
    float maxHeight = h;
    float maxWidth = w;
    float imgRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth/maxHeight;
    float compressionQuality = 0.8;//50 percent compression

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth)
    {
        if(imgRatio < maxRatio)
        {
            //adjust width according to maxHeight
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
            actualHeight = maxHeight;
        }
        else if(imgRatio > maxRatio)
        {
            //adjust height according to maxWidth
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
            actualWidth = maxWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            actualHeight = maxHeight;
            actualWidth = maxWidth;
        }
    }
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,NO,0.0);
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, compressionQuality);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

Below is my actual image

[image]

After cropping I am getting like below

[image]

All of my examples are stretching the image But i want with out stretching need to scale the image.Where i am missing?Please help me.

Comment: picker.allowsEditing = YES; when you capture image and select image at that time set one property and try it with droping

Comment: one more thnik just set imageview property aspect fit instead of scall to fill

Comment: I think, It is your size issue print your width and height after resizing image. I think you will get a rectangular frame thats why image is like that

Comment: print actualwidth and actualheight

Comment: I am getting problem only when i take the images from potrait mode landscape mode working fine

Comment: actualHeight==3264.000000,actualWidth==2448.000000

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using will resize your image, We use it for image compression or image resizing.
If you want to crop an Image there are two way.
1)Allow user to edit when image is selected.
You can achieve this by adding allowEditing property to picker like,

```
pickerView.allowEditing = true
```

This will give you rectangle to crop image, you can retrieve edited image from **didFinish** method of picker view

2)Programatically

- To crop image programatically you need to pass frame for cropping.

Here is the function i am using

```
func croppImage(originalImage:UIImage, toRect rect:CGRect) -> UIImage{

var imageRef:CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(originalImage.CGImage, rect)
var croppedimage:UIImage = UIImage(CGImage:imageRef)
return croppedimage
}
```

The above code will return you cropped image.

Comment: i tried this above two methods but cropped image streching

Comment: the image will stretch if your UIImageView has different spect ratio then your cropped image. Use aspectFit in content mode.

Comment: i accept that but i need to fill my image in uiimageview. if i use aspectFit  it won't fill right? in that case what should i do?

Comment: Yes, it wont fill your image view.  There is no such way that you can show your portrait image in landscape image view fill and not stretched . or at least i don't know way yet.

Answer (score 0):

These will crop your image into size you required.

```
- (CGImageRef)newTransformedImage:(CGAffineTransform)transform
                      sourceImage:(CGImageRef)sourceImage
                       sourceSize:(CGSize)sourceSize
                sourceOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)sourceOrientation
                      outputWidth:(CGFloat)outputWidth
                         cropSize:(CGSize)cropSize
                    imageViewSize:(CGSize)imageViewSize
{
    CGImageRef source = [self newScaledImage:sourceImage
                             withOrientation:sourceOrientation
                                      toSize:sourceSize
                                 withQuality:kCGInterpolationNone];

    CGFloat aspect = cropSize.height/cropSize.width;
    CGSize outputSize = CGSizeMake(outputWidth, outputWidth*aspect);

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                 outputSize.width,
                                                 outputSize.height,
                                                 CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(source),
                                                 0,
                                                 CGImageGetColorSpace(source),
                                                 CGImageGetBitmapInfo(source));
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, outputSize.width, outputSize.height));

    CGAffineTransform uiCoords = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(outputSize.width / cropSize.width,
                                                            outputSize.height / cropSize.height);
    uiCoords = CGAffineTransformTranslate(uiCoords, cropSize.width/2.0, cropSize.height / 2.0);
    uiCoords = CGAffineTransformScale(uiCoords, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, uiCoords);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(-imageViewSize.width/2.0,
                                           -imageViewSize.height/2.0,
                                           imageViewSize.width,
                                           imageViewSize.height)
                       , source);

    CGImageRef resultRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGImageRelease(source);
    return resultRef;
}

- (CGImageRef)newScaledImage:(CGImageRef)source withOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation toSize:(CGSize)size withQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality
{
    CGSize srcSize = size;
    CGFloat rotation = 0.0;

    switch(orientation)
    {
        case UIImageOrientationUp: {
            rotation = 0;
        } break;
        case UIImageOrientationDown: {
            rotation = M_PI;
        } break;
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:{
            rotation = M_PI_2;
            srcSize = CGSizeMake(size.height, size.width);
        } break;
        case UIImageOrientationRight: {
            rotation = -M_PI_2;
            srcSize = CGSizeMake(size.height, size.width);
        } break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                 size.width,
                                                 size.height,
                                                 8,  //CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(source),
                                                 0,
                                                 CGImageGetColorSpace(source),
                                                 (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst  //CGImageGetBitmapInfo(source)
                                                 );

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, quality);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context,  size.width/2,  size.height/2);
    CGContextRotateCTM(context,rotation);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(-srcSize.width/2 ,
                                           -srcSize.height/2,
                                           srcSize.width,
                                           srcSize.height),
                       source);

    CGImageRef resultRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    return resultRef;
}
```

///where you want to crop.

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [self newTransformedImage:transform
                                    sourceImage:self.image.CGImage
                                     sourceSize:self.image.size
                              sourceOrientation:self.image.imageOrientation
                                    outputWidth:self.image.size.width
                                       cropSize:self.photoView.cropView.frame.size
                                  imageViewSize:self.photoView.photoContentView.bounds.size];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Thank you. Enjoy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the replay how can assign to my image.

Comment: I updated the above post . Check it. Please Vote my answer if you get that you want.